# Wizard with Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.4, wizard

I'm trying to implement a wizard with Laravel.

Let's say we have three models: `post`, `contact` and `place`, and their relationship is as follows:

- `post <> contact`: Many to One
- `post <> place`: Many to One

Now the routes (for the wizard) would look something like that:

- `/wizard`: Stores a new `post`
- `/wizard/{post}/contact`: Stores a new contact and sets the relationship
- `/wizard/{post}/place`: Stores a new place and sets the relationship

One should be able to update each of these models independently from the wizard, therefore we would have a resource controller for each model and its corresponding routes (e.g. `/post/{post}/edit`).

Would I have a separate controller for the wizard? If so, would this controller implement all the methods `create`, `store`, `update` etc., even though we already have them implemented in each controller for a specific model?

I'd much rather redirect to the specific model controller, but I think then I'd have to mess with e.g. session variables to check if the model is being edited in the wizard or 'standalone'.

Comment: You need 3 resource controllers and a wizard controller I think. The wizard won't actually be responsible in updating anything though, it will just wrap around the appropriate resource routes.

Comment: How would I implement that?
I assume the wizard controller would redirect to a resource controller's action. But how would this controller (e.g. the `contact` controller) know, to which `post` is should set the relationship?

Comment: If I get you correctly, then at `/wizard/` you'd have a "wizard" to create a new post right presumably via a form. The form action should be `/post/create` (or whatever the post storing place is), or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, that's how I thought. But then you have the following problem:

How would `/post/create` know, where to redirect next (is it called from the wizard or 'standalone')

Comment: `redirect()->back()` instead of a specific route

Comment: Also `url()->previous()` has the URL you came from

Comment: But this would redirect me back to the form, where I just entered the data, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. You can check the previous if you need to make a decision on where to redirect.

Comment: Uh okay, seem's a little weird to me to solve it like that

Comment: No reason you can't put it all in one controller - there's no hard or fast rule there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem the following way:

Models which are related to an other model (such as `contact` and `phone`, both related to `post`) are accessed with a route such as `/{post}/comment/...` where `...` corresponds to a CRUD-operation.

Each model does its work it's supposed to do but redirects *always* to another controller (let's call it `WizardController`), which routes to the next controller. How does it know which one is the next? In my case I check if a variable / reference has been set (or is `null`) and take appropriate action.